# Download a file from S3 using full URI using AWS SDK for Go

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

The examples I've seen for downloading a file from S3 using the AWS SDK for Go are of the form:

```
downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(session, /* other args */)

s3object := &s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(myBucket),
    Key: aws.String(myKey),
}

bytesDownloaded, err := downloader.Download(myFile, s3object)
```

That is, one uses the bucket and key to specify the file. But what if I already have the full URI of the file on S3?  E.g.:

`https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myBucket/myKey`

Is there a way using the SDK to specify the file to download using the URL directly?

No, the bucket is *not* public.  In the SDK, I'm also setting the access and secret keys (elided from the example code).

Lastly, if it's simply not possible to do what I'm asking via the SDK, that's an acceptable (though not desired) answer.

Comment: Is the bucket public? `http.Get`, no SDK required. Just making sure you're seeing the forest.

Comment: No, the bucket is not public. (I've updated the question to state this explicitly.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want. The only ways to get a private object are:

1. Use the bucket and key to download the file
2. Generate a presigned URL an do an `http.Get` on that URL (to generate the presigned URL you need the bucket and key)

If you really want to use the URL I recommend you create a wrapper around `s3.GetObjectInput` that accepts the URL as an argument, parses it and then create the `s3.GetObjectInput` object.

Also, I don't know if you could do this it depends on your use case, but if you are storing the URLs somewhere and that's why you want to use them, you can consider storing instead the presigned url with a long expiration time, and then when you want to fetch the object you can just use that URL.

Comment: max lifetime for presigned url is 7 days, so not the best idea to just store and retrieve them later

Answer (score 3):

Created new S3URLtoURI parser for this.

```
func S3URLtoURI(s3Url string) (map[string]string, error) {
    m := make(map[string]string)
    u, err := url.Parse(s3Url)
    if err != nil {
        return m, err
    }

    if u.Scheme == "s3" {
        //s3: //bucket/key
        m["bucket"] = u.Host
        m["key"] = strings.TrimLeft(u.Path, "/")
    } else if u.Scheme == "https" {
        host := strings.SplitN(u.Host, ".", 2)
        if host[0] == "s3" {
            // No bucket name in the host;
            path := strings.SplitN(u.Path, "/", 3)
            m["bucket"] = path[1]
            m["key"] = path[2]
        } else { //bucket name in host
            m["bucket"] = host[0]
            m["key"] = strings.TrimLeft(u.Path, "/")
        }

    }
    return m, err
}
```

Runnable: https://play.golang.org/p/vkPJ7E4Fyno

Answer (score 2):

You could parse the URL to get the bucket and key:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    u, err := url.Parse("https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myBucket/myKey/morekey")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    path := strings.SplitN(u.Path, "/", 3)
    bucket := path[1]
    key := path[2]
    fmt.Println(bucket)
    fmt.Println(key)
}
```

Runnable: https://play.golang.org/p/G3Mxmm4f4qM

Comment: Yes, I know I can parse it. I asked specifically if there is a way to use the SDK directly.

Comment: Use the path package to work with paths. It will deal with double slashes correctly, for instance.

Comment: @Peter What does the path package have to do with the AWS SDK for Go?

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas, nothing. It has to do with URL parsing. The strings.Split* functions are unsuitable unless the URL is normalized (contains no double slashes, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Here you first need to enable public access on the object that you are trying to download from S3. You could achieve this by either of following approach.

- Make object publicly readable. But remember, whoever got access on
  the resource url can download your object from S3.
- Grant an anonymous access to your S3 bucket through bucket policies. [Refer 
  here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html) to read about this approach with policy samples. Remember to verify 
  what you expose when you go in this route.
- Use a [PreSignedUrl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) that permit to download the object in time-limited 
  manner. This is what I would prefer from aforementioned approaches.

Now last step would be to use go's [http client](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) to make the call to your pre-signed url and download the required object.

Comment: No, the object can not be publicly readable. (I've updated my question.) The object must only be accessible by the owner, so I don't believe any of your proposals will work.